# Directly reading data from netCDF files in a django view vs. inserting data from the NetCDF into a database + querying the data in the view?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, netcdf, python-xarray

For a django application, I need to process multiple netCDF files each day. Each file contains a 3-dimensional data array (latitude, longitude, time) of one variable with with a shape of (1000, 1000, 24).

In some views of the django application I want to access specific values of these data arrays, i.e. the time series on a specific location (given the latitude and longitude) or the entire map of a variable at a specific point in time.

In data science projects, I typically do this by opening the file with xarray (`xarray.open_dataset('file.nc')`) and using xarray's `.sel()` to select the desired values.

In the django application, I currently store the variables in a model that looks like the following:

```
class Geoid(models.model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()

class Timestamp(models.model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()

class Variable(models.model):
    geoid = models.ForgeinKey(Geoid)
    time = models.ForgeinKey(Timestamp)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

I realized that inserting the 1000x1000x24 = 24,000,000 data points of each file into the database takes too much time even if I use django's `.bulk_create()` method.

This led me to my questions:

**Would it actually be better to directly read the data in a django view from the netCDF files using xarray? What would be the pros and cons?**

I looked into GeoDjango and the available `RasterField` but I could not find a method how to lookup pixel values (i.e. given the latitude and the longitude) of a `RasterField` in a fast and clean way.

Comment: Hey Paul, did you ever arrive at answer? I was mulling the same question myself.

Comment: Hey Dt23, it really depends on you use case. 

But I think it is not a good idea in general to store large multidimensional data such as weather model data in a relational database. 

Use a netcdf or a zarr and directly read the data from them in your django views. Here, you should use chunking. When you mostly read your data along the time axis, your chunk size along the time axis should be larger than along the spatial axis such that you have good read performance.

There is maybe as well an intermediate solution in which you could try to store data in a BinaryField of a postgres db.